# Remove the space between the bars in a bar chart?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, bar-chart

Is it possible to remove the space between the bars in a bar chart in JavaFX? Where is the option?

Answer (score 0):

`barGap` and/ or `categoryGap` does this:

```
<BarChart fx:id="chart" barGap="0" categoryGap="0" animated="false" maxWidth="Infinity"
        HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" maxHeight="100" prefHeight="60" minHeight="40">
    <xAxis>
        <CategoryAxis fx:id="xAxis" tickLabelsVisible="false" />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
        <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" tickLabelsVisible="false" />
    </yAxis>
</BarChart>
```

[image]